# Ember model relationship not matching API

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two models who look like this:

```
// models/database.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
   title: DS.attr(),
   /*...*/
   documents: DS.hasMany('document')
});

// models/document.js
export default DS.model.extend({
   name: DS.attr(),
   /*...*/
   database: DS.belongsTo('database')
});
```

Is also have some routes

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('databases', function() {
    this.route('database', { path: ":database_id" }, function() {
      this.route('documents');
    });
  });
});
```

When I call **/database/[ID]/documents** if got nothing.

I think the problem is I'm working with an JSON HAL API and when I ask for databases on API I receive this kind of response.

```
{
"_embedded": {
    "databases": [
        {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "<API_URL>/databases/7ec39267b544424c/",
                    "reference": "7ec39267b544424c",
                    "title": "00000006"
                }
            },
            "database": {
                "name": "00000006",
                "reference": "7ec39267b544424c",
                "title": "****"
            }
        },
        {
            "_links": {
                "self": {
                    "href": "<API_URL>/databases/aace19af004144a4/",
                    "reference": "aace19af004144a4",
                    "title": "00000007"
                }
            },
            "database": {
                "name": "00000007",
                "reference": "aace19af004144a4",
                "title": "******"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

As you can see there no documents attributes on JSON returned.
If I want a database's documents I've got to call **[API_URL]/databases/[ID]/domains/[ID]/documents**

There's still a way to link documents to a database by specifying that the documents are recoverable at this URL (**/databases/[ID]/domains/[ID]/Documents**)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a [HAL API](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html) to [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/implementations/) converter. To avoid doing this yourself manually I'd recommend the http://github.com/201-created/ember-data-hal-9000 Ember plugin, which I've used myself to get Ember Data to play nice with Spring Boot.

If you wanted to see a simple example here's my [client-side](https://github.com/ericop/pizza-ember-spring-boot) and [server-side](https://github.com/ericop/pizza-ember-spring-boot-backend) demo app.

Additionally, if you were curious what Ember, and JSON API don't use HAL you can read here [JSON API - FAQ on HAL](http://jsonapi.org/faq/#why-not-use-the-hal-specification).

Comment: I'm already using ember-data-hal-9000 but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Eric, could you show any example using ember-data-hal-9000 with current ember version?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

I've override extractRelationships method in hal serializer like this:

```
extractRelationships(modelClass, resourceHash, included) {
    resourceHash._links["documents"] = {
        "href" : "/databases/" + resourceHash.id + "/domains/" + (resourceHash.name || resourceHash[modelClass.modelName].name) + "/documents/"
    };
    return this._super(modelClass, resourceHash, included);
}
```

I just add a link to documents for each databases returned by the API.

I've modified my route for **documents** like this

```
export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    model() {
        return this.modelFor('databases.database').get('documents');
    }
});
```

And now it works perfectly.